# I need some code that was made available by a student 15 years ago, but is no longer online. How can I contact someone in the group to get the code?

Tags: research-process, code

I need Matlab code of a method to compare it with the results of my proposed method.

The method which I want to use happened to be available online by a research group in a university in US in 1997  [[see here]](http://www.crpc.rice.edu/newsletters/win97/news_NBI.html). Unfortunately, when I click the [corresponding link](http://www.caam.rice.edu/~indra/NBIhomepage.html) of the method, it gives a server Error message. I've tried to email the person who seems to be responsible for [this page](http://softlib.rice.edu/NBI.html), but I didn't get a reply.   [This page](http://softlib.rice.edu/nbilicreg.html) also returns a server error.

As I urgently need this code, what should I do to contact to this research group?

Also, how can I convince them to give me the code?

Comment: Have you tried the wayback machine?  If that doesn't work, look for current contact info for the developers.

Comment: What is `wayback machine`? Also, Do you think I should contact the developer directly? It's a good try but I am pretty sure he wont reply coz he is so famous in his field(maybe top 10). @Kimball

Comment: Did you try [this](http://softlib.rice.edu/nbilicreg.html) (a registration page that looks like it links to the NBI software. Never mind; I clicked through and it didn't link to anything.

Comment: Yes, I fill out the registration form, but after accepting the lisence at the bottom of the page it returned me to a server error, i.e., page not found. @mkennedy

Comment: Here's the linkedin page of [Indraneel Das](https://www.linkedin.com/pub/indraneel-das/1/363/259)

Comment: Thanks, I wil try to contact him and see what will happen. @mkennedy

Comment: sorry sorry, it was another guy, I edited my comment. @mkennedy

Comment: Check out [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20070224123727/http://www.caam.rice.edu/~indra/NBIhomepage.html) I found on the "wayback machine"; all the way at the bottom of the page you can find some details.

Comment: That package is from 1997! Even in the *highly unlikely* event that you were able to get your hands on it, I wouldn't expect it to run on a modern MATLAB system without a *lot* of effort on your part.

Comment: @ff524 I have a lot of MATLAB code from around 1997 that still runs just fine.

Comment: @MadJack Thanks I found the most recent version of that codes from the link you gave me. Unfortunately, the latest update if for Matlab version 5 and I cannot run it on my 2014.

Comment: I got the most updated, version 5, code of the method. Sadly, you are right, there are a lot of errors due to matlab functions modification in the recent versions. Many functions have been removed or severely changed.@ff524

Answer (score 10):

PhD students come and move on, so if you are looking for code that isn't exactly brand new then contacting the responsible professor is usually your best bet. That being said, I would not get my hopes up too much that you get your code "urgently". There is a good chance that even the responsible professor will need to do some good ol' digging before (s)he unearths this material, if at all (and then there is still a good chance that nobody knows anymore how to make it work, or that it does not run anymore on today's platforms). Assume that this is going to be a bit of a project on its own.

Comment: well, still at their website they put a form that you can fill out and get the code. it seems they are a big  research team. If they didnt want me to download the codes so they wouldnt put that form and other stuff to address the free package, I guess, its a server error and technical. So I should find a way to let them know there is a problem in their website. @xLeitix

Comment: @Electricman "If they didnt want me to download the codes so they wouldnt put that form and other stuff to address the free pack" - All we know is that in 1997, when they put up that page, there was someone interested in disseminating the code. That person is now long gone, and it's highly likely that nobody else cares. The fact that the website still has the form just means that nobody bothered to take it down.

Comment: @Electricman If anything, the fact that the form is still there is probably a bad sign, not a good one. It means that the site has probably been completely forgotten and untouched for years. I'm guessing that your requests are all going to some long-defunct email inbox that hasn't been checked in a decade.

Answer (score 4):

The [MATLAB R13SP2 Model-Based Calibration Toolbox](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/releases/R13sp2/pdf_doc/mbc/cage.pdf) (hopefully the link works without a MATLAB license/account) contained the NBI algorithm:

> To understand the options for the NBI algorithm, some limited understanding of the algorithm is required. For more information on the NBI algorithm, see the NBI home page at the following URL: http://www.caam.rice.edu/~indra/NBIhomepage.html

While the NBI link is dead, it is the same link you are asking about, so it is potentially the same algorithm.

MATLAB R13SP2 (6.5.2) was released in 2003 so is not quite as old as the original link, but it is still old. I cannot find any documentation which says that newer releases of MATLAB contain the NBI algorithm (but nor did I find any documentation that it has been removed). My Mathworks account and license allows me to download R13SP2. The [system requirements](http://uk.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/release13/index.html) suggest it should work on Windows XP or 32 bit Linux (you might need an old kernel and glibc).

Comment: Yea I saw that toolbox before, But it's not available for my Matlab 2014. So should I contact my university to get the 2003 version of Matlab? Also that NBI homepage doesn't work.I have mac OSX 10.9, but my university only has windows version in the best condition. @StrongBad

Comment: @Electricman I would email the Mathworks and ask what version it was removed and then figure out how to get access to that version.

Comment: It seems like a good idea. I will do that. Thanks @StrongBad

Comment: I found the recent updated codes of that method from wayback machine. the version is still too old, i.e., version 5. there are many many errors due to matlab functions modification in the recent versions and also I cannot have old version of matlab